# Logic to find the nearest possible sum of array values to target

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

This is a simpler version of knapsack, which I am having trouble wrapping my head around.

In my version I don't care how valuable the items are. I just want to get as close to the weight capacity as possible, and order doesn't matter because I'm doing it multiple times and shuffling in between.

So to be clear:
I have an array of values like: `weights = [{44, 52, 100, 33, 33, 22, 25, 4, 6, 77, 88, 45}]` and a capacity of, for example:`capacity: 204`

I want the closest combination of array values to that capacity number without repeating any, I'm not super great at math, and the wikipedia article has completely lost me.

Can someone explain how to get this?

Comment: It's not really a lot simpler. [It's known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Subset-sum_problem) as "*the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) [which] is a special case of the decision and 0-1 problems where each kind of item, the weight equals the value*"

Comment: Ohhh that's interesting. I'll mess around with that exponential time algorithm part. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach: cycle through all subsets of N numbers, and check the sum of weights. Running time is O(2^N*N)

You can try dynamic programming.
The problem can be divided into 2 subproblems, to check whether the sum of set is equal to or less than the capacity.
1) Include the current element in subset, and recur for the remaining items with remaining sum.
2) Exclude the current element from the subset, recur remaining items.
The base case of the recursion would be when no items are left. Finally, we output the items included in the subset.
Running time is O(n*capacity) in O(n)